# How can I ask a remote server that was never connected with my local machine to connect with me by SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, scp, ansible-playbook

I use an old server, that has not been updated and that cannot be updated.

The OS is FreeBSD, there is no Python, obviously Ansible, and no sshpass.

I access this old server from my personal computer using Ansible and ssh. Both of them (my computer and the old servers are communicating via a VPN).

The old server is in a network that has different (many) clients to whom I want to send files using SCP.

There is no DNS (I really cannot make one).

Knowing that I cannot reach the clients directly (I really can't), I have to establish a ssh connection (I really have to) between the old server and the clients. Once done I will be able to use my Ansible playbooks which are on my computer to make the old server send a file to its clients using a shell script.

Unfortunately ssh-copy-id and ssh @ won't work automatically. Manually I would have be prompted with a question about the fingerprint that will need a manual "yes" input and validation.

Or I will be asked to enter the user password.

I want to avoid that.

One idea that I have had is that it would be great if there was a Linux command like a kind of ping that could tell the client: "Hey! I know your IP address. Please initiate (by yourself) a connection with me using 'ssh old_server_user@old_server_IP' and don't worry I agree whoever you are, whoever you look like, whatever your signature is!"

Is it possible?

Comment: You can avoid the fingerprint question by switching off strict host checking https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh, but if the clients require authentication, you need to authenticate in order to remote-control them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making ansible use your old freebsd host to be it's jump server ?

Something like this one https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2020/10/26/use-a-ssh-jump-host-with-ansible/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Loca Port Forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example#local-forwarding) for your ssh to the old server?

```
ssh -L 2222:REMOTE_CLIENT_IP:22 USER@OLD_SERVER_IP
```

This tells to ssh that tunnels any connection to port 2222 of your localhost to the **old server** and the **old server** forwards that connection to port 22 of the **REMOTE_CLIENT_IP** and gets the response back to you.

[image: What is an SSH tunnel?]

Then you can ssh to the **remote client** using this command:

```
ssh -p 2222 REMOTE_CLIENT_USER@localhost
```

Also, have a look at [SSH tunnel via multiple hops](https://superuser.com/a/97007/621377)